# Catch an event fired on a website embedded in a winform

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms, events

I have a web page that is embedded in my winform.

When i click a button on my application the form shows up and navigates to a settings page.

What i want is to catch an event fired on the website.
e.g. if the user changes some settings on the webpage and clicks OK then i should catch that even and close my form automatically.

Is this even possible?

Here is the JS code for the OK click event

```
if (statusOK) {
Ext.Msg.show({
title : '',
buttons : Ext.Msg.OK,
msg : 'Default settings saved.',
 icon : Ext.Msg.INFO
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following in javascript

```
 window.external.MyFunction();
```

That will call the MyFunction() function in winforms.

In your cs file you need:

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
```

before your class definition. And `MyFunction()` needs to be public. In that function you can do to your form whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.. but is there a way i can avoid modifying the javascript..
I have the button ID.. Is there no way to check if that was clicked?

Comment: Is it possible to add the function to the javascript from my code as the page loads? This way i can modify the JS on the fly catch the event too.

Answer (score 1):

In your web page, you can do a redirect to some specialy crafted URL, like myapp://doStuff.

And in the web browser control, you can subscribe to `Navigating` event that will be fired when page tries to go to another URL. In that handler you can detect your specially crafted URLs and execute needed actions.